# play2 using main project views/controllers/models in submodule/subproject and inversely

Tags: java, scala, view, playframework-2.1, subproject

I have:

- main project
- sub project called "shopping"

I would like to use views from main project inside the subproject.
My code of sub project controller:

```
package controllers.shopping;

public class Application extends Controller {

  public static Result index() {
      return ok(views.html.confirmation.render("ok"));
  }
}
```

And my main build file

```
lazy val shopping = project.in(file("modules/shopping"))

val main = project.in(file("."))
    .dependsOn(shopping).aggregate(shopping)
```

My model class in submodule common:

```
@Entity
public class AppMode {
    public static AppMode getCurrentConfigurationEntry() {
        return JPA.em().find(AppMode.class, 1L);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since main depends on shopping adding a dependency the other way around as well would create a circular dependency so sbt wouldn't be able to know which project to build first.

Break the logic you want out into a second subproject that you depend on from both shopping and main and you will be able to access them in both shopping and main.

Comment: So You propose to create subproject "main" for all shared (between all submodules) logic. So what should I put in first project (not in module dir)?

Comment: I would rather call it "common" or something like that rather than "main". I would probably also try to keep the root project a superproject with no sources in and then submodules with the actual code. (I would claim this is best practice working with multimodule sbt projects)

Comment: Thanks for Your help. I will follow Your instruction :D

Comment: How Can I add a library to subproject. F.e. jpa library. To which one build should I put depedency and how to import in to source code?

Comment: You would need it for the subproject for compiling and maybe testing and you would need it for the end project for runtime. Checkout the sbt tutorial/docs to get a better understanding: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html

Comment: How can I access to models in submodule? I am getting an error:[IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: models.AppMode]
Which is in submodule common. I've tried already: models.common.AppMode and common.models.AppMode but it dosnt work.

Comment: During runtime the classes do not know what module/jar they come from, so if you put it in common/app/models then the package is common. Did you put a dependency from the module you are using it from to common?

Comment: I've changed package to package models.common;
And this resolve the problem. But another came out. Can You see at my next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842651/play2-calling-controllers-models-views-in-submodule

Comment: According to your instruction I've run into another problem. How configure jpa/hibernate in play framework to scan submodules models entity. I've created new posts for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846796/adding-jpa-hibernate-entity-in-submodule-in-playframework-to-entity-manager-to and the second one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25863415/how-to-persist-models-entity-in-playframework-submodule-using-jpa-hibernate/25863762?noredirect=1#25863762 CAN YOU HELP ME WITH THAT???