# How to persist models entity in playframework submodule using jpa/hibernate

Tags: hibernate, entity, playframework-2.2, subproject

I have project in PLAY FRAMEWORK which contain few submodules.

Each submodule has folder structure like this:

```
 - app:
  - controllers
  - **models**
  - views
 - conf:
  - submodulename.routes
 - build.sbt
```

I would like to persist all java class entities in folder: **models**.

How should I configure play framework and/or hibernate entity manager to scan this folders for entities.

I have example model class as follow:

```
package models.common;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import controllers.common.Index;
import play.data.validation.Constraints;
import play.db.jpa.JPA;

@Entity
public class AppMode {
    public static AppMode getCurrentConfigurationEntry() {
        return JPA.em().find(AppMode.class, 1L);
    }
//rest of code here- not important//
}
```

but in this state jvm return me a runtime error:

> [IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: models.common.AppMode]

NOTE : I'm using play 2.2.1

I've noticed that hibernate is correctly create SQL structure for AppMode entity
when I set this in persistance.xml:

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

But when I go further I am getting next error:

> [IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MIncident is not mapped

While I have annotation @Entity on that class.

**It seems to be correct mapped, but I can't do any operation like `hsql select` or `JPA.em().find()` on that entities**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out on my own.

Runtime error:

[IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: models.common.AppMode]
Is caused by Jpa/Hibernate configuration. Problem is that Jpa/Hibernate sees my entities (mark by annotation @Entity) while compilation, but in runtime dosn't. To fix that I've to manually point all my models class (entitites) in persistance.xml file as follow:

/conf/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
            <class>models.common.AppMode</class>
            <class>models.Customer</class>
            <class>models.Complaint</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Original post:
[package names (namespaces) in subproject classes in Play Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884772/package-names-namespaces-in-subproject-classes-in-play-framework/25905678#25905678)

I wonder why in main project (f.e: `/app/models/User.java`) I can use annotation `@javax.persistence.Entity` (and it works), but in sub project (f.e: `/modules/common/app/models/AppMode.java`) it dosnt work, the annotation `@javax.persistence.Entity` is not enought, I have to point each model class in persistance.xml file.

**I think it is a bug in playframework (I've checked 2.2.1, 2.2.4, and 2.3.4 versions)**

Comment: I was able to resolve this problem without explicitly defining models in persistence.xml. In my case I had multiple persistence.xml one in root project and one in sub module. Once I removed this from root project I was able to run it successfully. See https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5092