# build.sbt defining project dependency between modules

Tags: scala, build, sbt, playframework-2.2, cyclic-reference

I have project in PlayFramework.
It has one main project without any code/logic.
And it have few submodules:

- main:

  - admin
  - common
  - shop

Modules: admin and shop will base on common module (classes like: user, role, permission), so I have to configure it that way:

```
  lazy val shop = project.in(file("modules/shop"))
  .dependsOn(cirs)
  .dependsOn(common)
  .dependsOn(admin)  

  lazy val admin = project.in(file("modules/admin"))
  .dependsOn(cirs)
  .dependsOn(common)
  .dependsOn(shop)
```

But in module common I have view where I want to display links (a href...) to other submodules. To do this I have to use reverse routing classes, which are controllers in submodules: shop and admin. So I have to use something like that:

```
<a href="@controllers.shop.routes.Index.index">shop</a>
<a href="@controllers.admin.routes.Index.index">admin</a>
```

Which mean that I have to also add .dependsOn(shop).dependsOn(admin) for common module.

**But it cause a Cyclic dependencies, which is incorrect!**

Please help me.
How can I deal with it?

Comment: Do you need view in common? Remove your view - and add to root project. Root will depend on all subprojects.

Comment: It dosnt work, cause my controllers wich return that view is in submodule.